# Pack/unpack a 3 byte integer in Python with struct.pack

Tags: python, pack

I need to send a packet to a system, the problem is the specification states it must conform to the following:

```
Padding (set to zero) : 1 byte
Packet Length : 3 bytes
```

For the rest of the implementation, I have been using struct.pack() and struct.unpack(), but there isn't an option for a 3-byte integer.

Is there an easy way of achieving this?

Comment: It probably means 4-bytes total with 1 byte padding.  Anyway you can just add however many `b'\x00'` you need with plain old string addition/multiplication.

Comment: Well 1 padding byte + 3 data bytes = 4 total bytes... You can just use `i` (4 bytes) format and only allow integers in the range [0, 16777216) for positive values (or [-8388608, 8388607] for signed values)

Comment: A better description would probably have been "Packet length: 4 bytes; the high order byte must be 0x00" or the like.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The max value is 16,777,215.  Would I need to set the endian?

Comment: @chepner What I typed is exactly how the message specification documents it.

Comment: @GemmaMorriss Yes; I'm saying whoever wrote the specification could have been clearer. Also, the endianness needs to be specified by the specification. If the padding *precedes* the packet, you can probably assume network byte order (i.e., big endian).

Comment: @chepner would the struct.pack format be ">i" ?

Comment: @GemmaMorriss If it is a signed value, yes. You could also use `'!i'`, which I've seen described as "for people who can't remember if network order is big- or little-endian". If the value is supposed to be unsigned, use `'>I'` or `'!I'`.

Comment: The specification is for the SMB 2 protocol, therefore 'network' related.  There is a single byte zero pad with the signed value specifying the size of the actual message.  Sorry if I am being slow, but, is '!i' the correct answer?

Comment: SMB2 supposedly (I'm not terribly familiar with it) requires all multibyte integers to be represented in little-endian order.

Comment: 3 bytes packet length would be very odd, pardon the pun  :)